# PyObject_CallObject crashed when called out of main function scope

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api

I'm building a simple module to wrap a C function. The main function of this module (`test_wrapper`) basically receives a python function and call it:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject* test_wrapper(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
    PyObject* py_handler;
    int args_ok = PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &py_handler);

    PyObject_CallObject(py_handler, NULL);

    return Py_BuildValue("i", 0);
}

static PyMethodDef TestModuleMethods[] = {
    { "test", test_wrapper, METH_VARARGS, NULL },
    { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }
};

static struct PyModuleDef TestModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "test_module",
    NULL,
    -1,
    TestModuleMethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_test_module(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&TestModule);
}
```

The code above works fine. The thing is, let's suppose I need to call the passed python function (`py_handler`) in the future in another way, by a signal handler, for example, and now it expects an integer as an argument:

```
PyObject* py_handler;

void handler(int signo) {
    PyObject* handler_args = PyTuple_Pack(1, PyLong_FromLong(signo));
    PyObject_CallObject(py_handler, handler_args); //seg fault
}

static PyObject* test_wrapper(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
    int args_ok = PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &py_handler);
    //Py_INCREF(py_handler); //adding this didn't work

    //calls sigaction to set handler function

    return Py_BuildValue("i", 0);
}
```

By doing this, PyObject_CallObject crashes (seg fault) when it's called by `handler`.

What could I be missing here?

If relevant, I'm building the `.so` with `setup.py`.

Comment: First you need to find out whether you are allowed to call Python stuff from a C signal handler. (I suspect not.)

Comment: Probably the GIL?

Comment: It was the GIL! Thanks for the tips. Acquiring and releasing it solved the issue. Feel free to post an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have too much enthusiasm for writing an answer myself right now. So feel free to answer it yourself if you want (given you probably have some code that works by now...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acquiring and releasing GIL was enough to solve the problem:

```
void handler(int signo) {
    PyGILState_STATE state = PyGILState_Ensure();
    PyObject* handler_args = PyTuple_Pack(1, PyLong_FromLong(signo));
    PyObject_CallObject(py_handler, handler_args);
    PyGILState_Release(state);
}
```

Wrapping code in `PyGILState_STATE` object and after execution releasing it ensures that only one thread at a time is executing the Python code. In general, it's a good practice to acquire the **GIL** before calling any Python API function and release it afterwards.